# How to process files of different formats using spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My requirement is to poll two different directories for different format files (PSV and CSV) and to process it using spring batch.

I used inbound channel adapter to poll the directory . But , i couldnt able to find a way to call corresponding reader and its tokenizer and field mapper based on the type of file .

e.g. if it is psv - call PSV reader , PSV line mapper 
if it is csv - call CSVReader , CSV line mapper

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: the solution is to create your own reader and apply the corresponding logic based on the file extension

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777596/parsing-several-csv-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions.

I followed a different approach. I have setted the item reader and writer as a job parameter. So, based on file type , respective item reader and writer will be invoked

```
<chunk reader= "#{JobParameter[bean.reader]}" writer="#{JobParameter[bean.writer]}"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your Own `Reader` : `CustomFilesReader` :

```
public class CustomFilesReader implements InitializingBean{

    private List<File> yourFiles= null;

    public File read() {
        if ((yourFiles!= null) && (yourFiles.size() != 0)) {  
          return yourFiles.remove(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Reading Items from your dir
    private void loadItems() {
        this.yourFiles= new ArrayList<File>();
       // populate the items
     }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        loadItems();
    }
}
```

Register the bean :

```
<bean id="customFilesReader " class="mypackage.CustomFilesReader "/>


<bean id="myReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemReaderAdapter">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="customFilesReader " />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="read" />
</bean>
```

The Same thing can be Done for a custom `ItemProcessor` and a custom `ItemWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to create a class similar to `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` or `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`. That is to say, it would take a `Classifier`, a list of delegated `ItemReader` and choose the right `ItemReader` depending of the result of the `Classifier`.

Problem is, you don't have an input to classify, since the read isn't done yet. That's why I thought about using the `resource` property as the element to classify. Here's the result :

```
public class ResourceClassifierCompositeItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {

    private Classifier<String, ItemReader<? extends T>> classifier = new ClassifierSupport<String, ItemReader<? extends T>> (null);
    private Resource resource;

    public void setClassifier(Classifier<String, ItemReader<? extends T>> classifier) {
        this.classifier = classifier;
    }

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
        return readItem(classifier.classify(resource.getFilename()));
    }

    private T readItem(ItemReader<? extends T> reader) throws Exception {
        return reader.read();
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

}
```

Now for how to use it. First you'll need a `MultiResourceItemReader` to read both .PSV and .CSV at the same time. Then you'll have to delegate the read to the `ResourceClassifierCompositeItemReader`. You'll have to add a `BackToBackPatternClassifier` to classify the String `resource.getFilename()` (i.e. the file name) and call an `ItemReader` accordingly (via a `MatcherMap`). To do that, you'll need to write your own `RouterDelegate` (taking the filename, split it to get the extension, and return it as a String to be matched).