# How to use ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor in Spring Batch and write data into same table for Insert and Upsert?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I went through the link - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessorTests.java, but did not strike much out of it.

I am trying to replace ETL Informatica mapping logic into the Batch. I am looking to separate out `Status=I` and `Status=U` into separate (Individual) processor and then further perform lookup and massage the data and then write those records directly into the table for Status=I and for status=U, perform another complex logic (like lookups, massaging and match and merge logic) and then upsert those records again into the same table.

I've tried to do POC, where I am looking to segregate the records in the processor

CustomerClassifier.java

```
public class CustomerClassifier implements Classifier<Customer, ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer>> {

    private ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> insertCustomerProcessor;
    private ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> updateCustomerProcessor;
    
    public CustomerClassifier(ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> evenCustomerProcessor, ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> oddCustomerProcessor) {
        this.insertCustomerProcessor= insertCustomerProcessor;
        this.updateCustomerProcessor= updateCustomerProcessor;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
        return customer.getStatus().equals("I") ? insertCustomerProcessor : updateCustomerProcessor;
    }
}
```

OddCustomerProcessor.java

```
public class OddCustomerProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer process(Customer item) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        // Perform some msaaging and lookups here
        customer.setId(item.getId());
        customer.setFirstName(item.getFirstName());
        customer.setLastName(item.getLastName());
        customer.setBirthdate(item.getBirthdate());
        customer.setStatus(item.getStatus());
        return customer;
    }
}
```

EvenCustomerProcessor.java

```
public class EvenCustomerProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer process(Customer item) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        // Perform some msaaging and lookups here
        customer.setId(item.getId());
        customer.setFirstName(item.getFirstName());
        customer.setLastName(item.getLastName());
        customer.setBirthdate(item.getBirthdate());
        customer.setStatus(item.getStatus());
        return customer;
    }
}
```

CustomLineAggregator.java

```
public class CustomLineAggregator implements LineAggregator<Customer> {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String aggregate(Customer item) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to serialize Customer", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthdate;
    private String status;
}
```

**Error-**

> The method setClassifier(Classifier<? super Customer,ItemProcessor<?,? extends Customer>>) in the type ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<Customer,Customer> is not applicable for the
> arguments (CustomerClassifier)

Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> customerPagingItemReader(){
        // reading database records using JDBC in a paging fashion
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(1000);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());
        
        // Sort Keys
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
        
        // MySQL implementation of a PagingQueryProvider using database specific features.
        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from customer");
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
        
        return reader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public EvenCustomerProcessor evenCustomerProcessor() {
        return new EvenCustomerProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OddCustomerProcessor oddCustomerProcessor() {
        return new OddCustomerProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter(){
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    batchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    batchItemWriter.setSql(""); // Query Goes here
    return batchItemWriter;
}
    
    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor() throws Exception{
        ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> itemProcessor = new ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<>();
        itemProcessor.setClassifier(new CustomerClassifier(evenCustomerProcessor(), oddCustomerProcessor()));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
                .reader(customerPagingItemReader())
                .processor(classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it intended that `step1` does not use any item processor? I guess you are planning to use `classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor` as item processor.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I've added, please help me to solve the issue by reading my problem statement and thanks in advance for direction and consulting

Comment: Your code does not compile, the method `classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor()` should return the item processor: `return itemProcessor;`. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, Indeed agree, how can I segregate the records in process with Status=I and Status=U or how can I achieve this using ItemProcessor ?

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `CustomerClassifier` and define the composite item processor as follows:

```
@Bean
public ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor(
        EvenCustomerProcessor evenCustomerProcessor,
        OddCustomerProcessor oddCustomerProcessor
) {
    ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> itemProcessor = new ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<>();
    itemProcessor.setClassifier(new Classifier<Customer, ItemProcessor<?, ? extends Customer>>() {
        @Override
        public ItemProcessor<?, ? extends Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
            return customer.getStatus().equals("I") ? evenCustomerProcessor : oddCustomerProcessor;
        }
    });
    return itemProcessor;
}
```

Then update your step definition as follows:

```
@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
            .reader(customerPagingItemReader())
            .processor(classifierCustomerCompositeItemProcessor(evenCustomerProcessor(), oddCustomerProcessor()))
            .writer(customerItemWriter())
            .build();
}
```